# How to resolve "error: Failed to read Info.plist of app (Couldn't load Info dictionary for DVTFilePath)"

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm using Xcode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005)

The iOS app I'm trying to build was produced by duplicating an existing Mac version of the app, and changing the pertinent target OS settings. I've done this before successfully with another app without any major issues. However, the Info.plist file for this app (which was directly copied from the working app) is possibly causing some kind of issue.

- The "Info.plist file" setting in the Xcode Build Settings for the iOS version is set to the correct path. If I set it to a non-working path, I get a different error (ProcessInfoPlistFile reports an error)
- I checked the built app bundle, and it did contain an Info.plist file.

Here are the errors that my issue produced:

```
replacing existing signature
bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I worked around the first error by adding `--deep` to the codesign flags. After adding that I would get this error:

```
Validate /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/long string of characters/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my\ app\ name.app
    cd /Users/me/Perforce/workspace/project/Platforms/OSX
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.application
    builtin-validationUtility /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/long string of characters/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my\ app\ name.app

error: Failed to read Info.plist of app /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/long string of characters/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my app name.app (Couldn't load Info dictionary for <DVTFilePath:0x7f97125bb4b0:'/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/long string of characters/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/my app name.app'>)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue was occurring because I had a folder named "resources" in my app's root directory. Renaming this folder to "stuff" resolved this error, but is pretty inconvenient because of the way our resources are set up.

I'm guessing iOS has an undocumented "resources" folder in the app folder structure, and adding a "resources" folder to your app conflicts and overwrites some metadata in there.

The original error I was getting started appearing after I added `--deep` to my codesign flags, which was not actually needed.

Comment: I have the same issue but no folder named 'resources' in my case so the problem must be elsewhere. I'm using xCode 8.2.1

Comment: As with all NextStep bundles (`.app`, `.framework`, etc), there is indeed a `Resources` directory in the bundle. It's where all your resources are copied into. You can definitely have a `resources` directory in your project, but you shouldn't try copying it whole-cloth to the final app bundle. Instead, have Xcode copy the individual resources that you need, in the Copy Files build phase. Further reading: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1

Comment: It's totally undocumented on that page, and they clearly say to put your files in the top-level of the app bundle, imposing no restrictions on what you should call your folders. They even encourage putting files in a "resources" folder in macOS app bundles, yet following the same pattern in an iOS app causes this snafu.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue (no folder named 'resources' in my case so the problem was elsewhere). Using xCode 8.2.1

Solution: Ensure the Info.plist file is listed in the Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources section of each one of your targets.

Comment: Are you sure? I would expect that Info.plist inside the package should be only generated based on the project configuration ain a build step called ProcessInfoPlistFile.

```
Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file '/Users/anonymized/path/Info.plist'.
```

Comment: @VarunNaharia I would assume this answer is the more common case of this error appearing, but I am keeping my own answer as "accepted" because this answer was not the root cause of the problem I was encountering, as the question asker. (My original question even stated that the plist was being correctly copied.) Tooltip text for accepted: "it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution." The upvote system provides a fallback for promoting alternate answers to the the same or similar problems, so there's no reason to change the accepted answer.

Comment: I had this error resolved with a combination of adding the info.plist file to Copy Bundle Resources as stated above and updating my version of xcode to accommodate the version of iOS running on my device.

Answer (score 4):

For me, restarting my computer fixed the issue. Nothing else worked.

=/

Answer (score 3):

The same issue always happens after creating a folder such as the very common one supporting files or any other folderName and put your info.plist file in there.
Here is how to fix it: -
Project -> Targets -> Select your app -> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist -> Double tap the old file path and change it to the new file path.

for example, if you created a folder named Supporting Files and moved your info.plist file in there, the new file path should be: - YourAppName/**Supporting Files**/Info.plist

Answer (score 1):

In my case, changing the target device to an iOS simulator while building worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check the target of the Info.plist file by clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I solved based on part of @Mussa Charles' answer:

> Here is how to fix it: - Project -> Targets -> Select your app ->
> Build Settings -> Packaging -> Info.plist

There was no value in either the Debug or Release, so I copied the value from another of my working apps, and changed to current App name:

$(SRCROOT)/myAppName/Info.plist

(using Xcode Version 14.2)